# Creating Dummy Variable based on string values in another variable

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I am trying to create a dummy variable based on the string value of another variable the new dummy variable is including compound words. My question is how to get around this so it only includes the word in the quotes.

Syntax example "toke" = dataframe and "word" = a tokenized column of individual words when I run the syntax it correctly codes "product" as 1 in the new variable (`toke2$product`) but it will also code productdesign as a 1. I want it to only code product as 1 and productdesign as 0.

```
 tags <- c("product", "productdesign", "electronics")
line <- c("Bears", "Orcids", "Oranges") 
toke = data.frame(toke, tags)
toke

        toke2 <- toke%>% mutate(
          product = ifelse(str_detect(word, "product"), "1", "0"))
```

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You got my downvote because your `token` dataset is not reproducible. If you can fix that, I will retract my downvote and give you an upvote.

Comment: If you want to match only the word "product", use `str_detect(word, "^product$")`.

Comment: Okay, I think that simple dataset will do the trick although I am not sure if it will work with the mutate and ifselse functions.

Comment: @neilfws thank you for the suggestion I'll give it a try!

Comment: I think this works for a sample dataset @www

Comment: Thank you for your update. I have retracted my downvote and given you an upvote.